# Annular regions for which this Laurent series converges

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, laurent-series

Given the Laurent series $$\sum_{n= - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{3^n + 1}$$
Find the annular region for which it converges.
I'm struggling to find any similar examples or where to begin for this.

Comment: Well, you could try this $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{z^n}{3^n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{3^n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}\cdot\frac{1}{3^{-n}+1}$$ and set $t=\dfrac1z$...

Answer (score 0):

Following the excellent comment by G. Sassatelli (fill in details):

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^n}{3^n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n}{(3^n+1)z^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{3^n+1}$$

For the first sum above, we have

$$\left|\frac{\frac{3^{n+1}}{(3^{n+1}+1)z^{n+1}}}{\frac{3^n}{(3^n+1)z^n}}\right|=\frac{3(3^n+1)}{\left(3^{n+1}+1\right)|z|}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|z|^{-1}$$

For the second one:

$$\left|\frac{\frac{z^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}+1}}{\frac{z^n}{3^n+1}}\right|=\frac{(3^n+1)|z|}{3^{n+1}+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{|z|}3$$